# How to create a module using mongoose for sharing a changing DB connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i've been working on an app(Node.js with MongoDB using mongoose), and the server connects to 2 different databases, 1 generic containing username and password pairs for user authentication. Then, when the user signs in, I want to connect to a different database, named after the user's userId. I managed to create a module for sharing the generic UA database, but it's more difficult with the second one, since it doesn't open with the connection, but later on, when the user signs in. I guess i got inspired by the idea of react context kind of sharing.

So far i've got something like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/* 
  UA = User Authentication
  US = User Specific
  DB = DataBase
*/

const UA_DB = mongoose.createConnection(/*...*/);
);
const User = UA_DB.model("User", require("../../data-schemas/user"));
let US_DB, Order, Item, Ingredient, Place;
console.log("opened UA database");

function sendUserId(newUserId) {
  userId = newUserId;
  US_DB = mongoose.createConnection(/*... ${newUserId} ...*/ );
  Order = US_DB.model("Order", require("../../data-schemas/order"));
  Item = US_DB.model("Item", require("../../data-schemas/item"));
  Ingredient = US_DB.model(
    "Ingredient",
    require("../../data-schemas/ingredient")
  );
  Place = US_DB.model("Place", require("../../data-schemas/place"));
  console.log("opened US database");
}

module.exports = {
  UA_DB: {
    User,
  },
  US_DB: {
    Order,
    Item,
    Ingredient,
    Place,
  },
  sendUserId,
};
```

Now, if I hadn't made it clear, the first, UA_DB works just fine, the user signs in just fine... When it comes to the US_DB i always get undefined as values(Cannot read property 'find' of undefined). I suspect the problem could be, that the exported value doesn't update with the value of the variables. Any ideas, how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out. Instead of using precise values I use a function to return them, and to connect to the database.UserId is stored in a token, so after verification i check whether i am already connected to the right database (with the userId variable, which stores previous values) and then return curretn values of the models now my code looks something like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/* 
  UA = User Authentication
  US = User Specific
  DB = DataBase
*/

const UA_DB = mongoose.createConnection(/* ... */
);
const User = UA_DB.model("User", require("../../data-schemas/user"));
let US_DB,
  Order,
  Item,
  Ingredient,
  Place = "some default value";
console.log("opened UA database");

let userId = "";

function getUS_DBModels(newUserId) {
  if (newUserId !== userId) {
    userId = newUserId;
    US_DB = mongoose.createConnection(`...${userId}...`
    );
    Order = US_DB.model("Order", require("../../data-schemas/order"));
    Item = US_DB.model("Item", require("../../data-schemas/item"));
    console.log("opened a US_DB connection");
    Ingredient = US_DB.model(
      "Ingredient",
      require("../../data-schemas/ingredient")
    );
    Place = US_DB.model("Place", require("../../data-schemas/place"));
  }
  return {
    Order, Item, Ingredient, Place
  }
}

module.exports = {
  UA_DB: {
    User,
  },
  getUS_DBModels,
};
```

For anyone wondering, in different modules you can access the values like this

```
const dbHandler = require("./path/to/the/module");
const { Item } = dbHandler.getUS_DBModels("UserId");
```